# How to detect rotated and quite deformed object

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, object-detection

I have an A4 paper with some black stroked rectangle. I scan the image and try to use some basic OpenCV's function like template matching but I see the image I recive sometime rotated when I put it to the scanner or the paper somehow wrinkled so the template matching will not work.
I'm very new to image processing, I hope you can show me some step-to-step to fix my issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your object detector is confident to find objects based on a template with a certain scale and orientation, then all you have to do is to apply some scaling, rotation, or affine transformations to that query template and re-apply the search.

Eg. if your template T, is used on an image I, based on a search method S(T,I) then you can apply S, with many T-based products:

Scale: T1=0.5*T...Tn=1.5*T
Rotation: T1=R(T,-pi)...Tn=R(T,+pi)